# Why can't I access AutoCompleteBox in any function other than Main Window in WPF?

Tags: wpf, autocomplete

I am trying to do a

```
codebox.ItemsSource = codesList;
codebox.PopulateComplete();
```

from the Populating event I have created and I get the error

> "The name 'codebox' does not exist in the current context'

This was working when I just populated it from the MainWindow. Anyone know what I am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like it's because `codebox` is not visible from the scope of where your  [`Populating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.autocompletebox.populating%28VS.95%29.aspx) event handler is declared. When the `Populating` event handler is within `MainWindow`, the `codebox` control is "visible"  to that code. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for more info.

Where is your `Populating` event handler declared?

Also, note that the `sender` parameter in the `Populating` event should be a reference to `codebox`. You could simply cast this to an `AutoCompleteBox`, and it should work fine, e.g.:

```
private void Codebox_Populating(object sender, PopulatingEventArgs e)
{ 
    AutoCompleteBox _codebox = sender as AutoCompleteBox;

    // Use _codebox here instead of codebox
}
```

Comment: ugh, my box was actually called codeBox with a capital B, that was the problem. sorry for wasting your time and thanks for the help. lol

Comment: @Drew No worries, glad you got it figured out.